# Best Practices -- Hibernate persistence code inside the Entity itself?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, jpa, requestfactory

In Google's `RequestFactory` tutorials, they recommend putting my persistence logic (in my case, Hibernate) inside the Entity classes. Then they pose the question: "What if you don't want to implement persistence code in an entity itself?" and proceed to explain an alternate method.

My question: which is better, putting persistence logic inside the Entity class, or keeping all persistence logic in a separate class?

Any info is appreciated, thanks.

-tjw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Putting the persistence code in an entity itself is an **Active Record Pattern** approach while  keeping all persistence logic in a separate class is the **Repository Pattern** approach.  You can use the keyword `repository pattern vs activerecord`  to search more information about your questions.

For example ,active record pattern has a criticism about its testability  without a database , you can refer to [this](http://moleseyhill.com/blog/2009/07/13/active-record-verses-repository/) for more info .

For me , I prefer the Repository Pattern more as it is testable and I don't like  persistence codes and  domian business logic are mixed in one class which violates the emphasis on separation of concerns.