# Should objects in ORM contain operations other than CRUD?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, model

Let's say I have a User object for performing CRUD operations using ORM:

```
//Create a new User
$user = new User();
$user->name = "John Smith";
$user->age = 30;
$user->email = 'john@smith.com;
$user->save();
```

Similiar operations would also be avaliable for `Read`, `Update` and `Delete`.

But what about cases such as these:

- `deleteAllUsers() //delete all users`
- `getAllUsers() //get all users`
- `promoteUser() //change the user's 'rank' (not permissions) within a website`
- `addReputationPoints() //give the user x amount of reputation points`

Would these type of operations go into the `User` class? If not, where should they go? Should I have a class called `UserManager` that deals with these operations?

Comment: You might be interested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010764/best-practices-hibernate-persistence-code-inside-the-entity-itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the User class would extend an ORM class that provides the standard CRUD interface. The additional functions you talk about would very well fit within the User class itself.

It is always good practice to make 'fat models' and skinny controllers, i.e. put all logic that is directly related to data manipulation in the models, and only the 'overarching' logic in the controllers.

See e.g. here for more info http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model

Answer (score 0):

In my most favorite framework (Kohana), we have:

```
ORM::factory('user')->where(<whatever condition required>)->find_all();
```

and the corresponding `delete()` (replacing `find_all()` above). Are you writing your own ORM library? If yes, then you can make operations that deal with more than one record as class methods instead of instance methods. It's up to your design, however. Kohana, for instance, still make it instance method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you architecture your ORM solution.

My approach would be to **enclose collective actions** (made on multiple records at once) into some **class representing eg. database table** storing users or the one responsible for the basic ORM actions - depending whether they are table-specific or not.